# XML Concurrency

Tags: xml

I'm using this PHP Ajax Live Search (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) and the search results are coming from an XML file.

This search is going to be used by multiple users (around 50) and I want to know will there be any problems with multiple users getting search results from a single XML file.

The only person that will edit the XML file will be me. Everyone else will just be getting the search results from the file.

The reason I'm using an XML is that there are only 200 URL's in the XML and I thought it would be a simple way of searching it.

Will there be problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no concurrency errors if only you edit the file.

Only if you edit the file 2 times at once. (But thats weird so I dont think there will be problems)

Anyways... Using a database should be easier to edit and faster if your search is growing in the future. (with maybe more editors)